# Can't get my SpeakerRecord entity when joining with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have three tables: event, speaker, event_speaker

Events and speakers have an n:m relationship managed by the "event_speaker" table. I used the jOOQ maven codegen to generate files like "EventRecord" and "SpeakerRecord".

In my application I want to get all speakers for a particular event. So I need to join the "speaker" table with the "event_speaker" table to be able to limit the results by the event id:

```
return dsl.select(SPEAKER.asterisk())
        .from(SPEAKER)
        .leftJoin(EVENT_SPEAKER).on(SPEAKER.ID.eq(EVENT_SPEAKER.SPEAKER_ID))
        .where(EVENT_SPEAKER.EVENT_ID.eq(eventId))
        .fetch();
```

Now I'll get a `Result<Record>` as the return value. But I would like to get a `Result<SpeakerRecord>` as the return value. If I remove the join, I will get it (but of course the result set will contain all speakers, which I don't want).

How is it possible to get a `SpeakerRecord` in place of the more general `Record` object when I need a join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your `LEFT JOIN` is effectively an `INNER JOIN`](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/04/09/the-difference-between-sqls-join-on-clause-and-the-where-clause/) because your `WHERE` clause filters on the outer joined table, [but what you really wanted was a semi join](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/03/09/sql-join-or-exists-chances-are-youre-doing-it-wrong/). In the rare case you don't have a unique key on `EVENT_SPEAKER (SPEAKER_ID, EVENT_ID)`, e.g. because there's a third column in the key, you would get duplicates with your current query.

So, do this instead:

```java
return dsl
    .selectFrom(SPEAKER)
    .where(SPEAKER.ID.in(
        select(EVENT_SPEAKER.SPEAKER_ID)
        .from(EVENT_SPEAKER)
        .where(EVENT_SPEAKER.EVENT_ID.eq(eventId))
    ))
    .fetch();
```

Assuming, as always

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

With the above query, you can use [`DSLContext.selectFrom(Table)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#selectFrom(org.jooq.Table)) again, which produces your desired `SpeakerRecord`.

In other cases where you really need to join, [use Simon's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67958688/521799)

Comment: That's exactly what I need! The last time I used SQL on my own is about 15 years ago. I definitely need to work through a join tutorial to refresh my sleeping knowledge…

Comment: Btw, this is for [Komunumo](https://komunumo.org/), the new admin UI for the [Java User Group Switzerland](https://www.jug.ch/)…

Comment: @MarcusFihlon: Yeah, it can be confusing to think about which join type to choose. Here are a few posts from the jOOQ blog, which I think you might appreciate: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/01/12/a-probably-incomplete-comprehensive-guide-to-the-many-different-ways-to-join-tables-in-sql/ and of course from the jOOQ manual: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/joined-tables/

Comment: @MarcusFihlon: Great to hear you're using jOOQ for that platform! :) I'll be here for help if you need any!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fetchInto` to tell jOOQ what result you are expecting:

```
return dsl.select(SPEAKER.fields())
    .from(SPEAKER)
    .leftJoin(EVENT_SPEAKER).on(SPEAKER.ID.eq(EVENT_SPEAKER.SPEAKER_ID))
    .where(EVENT_SPEAKER.EVENT_ID.eq(eventId))
    .fetchInto(SpeakerRecord.class);
```